# Where can I find a good book on writing curses applications with perl?

Tags: perl, ncurses, curses

I have been in search of a good way to write curses apps.  So far I have found Curses::UI and Curses::Toolkit, but none of them are as maleable as I want them to be.  Now I'm looking to write my app with just Curses itself, and learn something about it in the process!  Are there any good books/tutorials/etc. that would teach me the guts of writing apps with Curses and Perl?  (I don't mind if it's written with another language, like C, in mind.  As long as I can translate what I read into Perl, it's fine!)

Thank you,

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, I have found [Writing programs with NCURSES](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-intro.html) to be very helpful.  [Programming with Curses](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780937175026) is also good, but it lacks a lot of things new to ncurses (e.g. colors), and it's pretty out-dated.  However, [Writing programs with NCURSES](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-intro.html) explains the newly added things, too.  I'm also making extensive use of `man ncurses` which is a great source of info *after* you've read the above ncurses intro.

Thank you for all the answers.

Answer (score 3):

I used the excellent [Programming with Curses](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780937175026) the last time I had to do this, which was more than a decade ago, but I'm sure the API hasn't changed much. The book is a fairly bare-bones reference to the C API, but the Perl Curses module mirrors  the C API pretty closely.

Comment: Wow I'm getting all kinds of university flashbacks now... :) that was a great book.